# Return an ID when the ID has conditions in multiple rows that have to be met

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query that returns IDs that have satisfied conditions from multiple rows using different values for the same column. For example

```
ID | EVENT  | STATUS
---------------------
1  | Create  | Success
1  | Activate | Success
2  | Create  | Success
2  | Activate | In Progress
```

I want orders that have both create and activate as a success. So the return row would be 1. If ID 2 had success for both actiavte and create then the return would be both 1 and 2.

I have tried

```
select ID, EVENT, STATUS
from EOMSCHEMA.AUDIT_RECORDS
where (event = 'Activate' and status = 'Completed') 
  and (event = 'Create' and status= 'Completed')
```

but I dont think the syntax is correct.

Thanks

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: Wouldn't that just check 1 condition and not the other?

Comment: You're too fast...

Comment: The issue with your code is that it's looking for one line to have an event of both Activate and Create.  You need to have them as separate checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
select ID, EVENT, STATUS
from EOMSCHEMA.AUDIT_RECORDS
where event = 'Activate' and status = 'Completed'
and ID IN(SELECT ID FROM EOMSCHEMA.AUDIT_RECORDS WHERE event = 'Create' and status= 'Completed')
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd find something like this the easiest to read and understand (give me everything from the first query that is also in the second query)

```
select id
  from audit_records
 where event = 'Activate'
   and status = 'Completed'
intersect
select id
  from audit_records
 where event = 'Create'
   and status = 'Completed'
```

But that may not be the most efficient way to write the query.  Something like

```
select id
  from audit_records
 where status = 'Completed'
   and event in ('Activate', 'Create')
 group by id
having count(distinct event) = 2
```

may be more efficient.  But it may not be as immediately obvious what it is doing.  Logically, it is getting all the rows where the `status` is "Completed" and the `event` is either "Activate" or "Create".  That gives you both rows where `id = 1` and only the first row where `id = 2`.  It then aggregates them by `id` and counts how many distinct `event` values there are.  `id = 1` has two distinct `event` value (both "Activate" and "Create") so it is returned.  `id = 2` has only one distinct `event` so it is eliminated.

If you're writing a query that needs to run occasionally and data volumes aren't too large, I'd prefer the `intersect` approach to maximize programmer understanding.  If you're doing this in a performance critical section of code, you'd probably want the `group by` with some comments explaining what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the columns of the table returned you can use EXISTS twice:

```
select t.ID, t.EVENT, t.STATUS
from EOMSCHEMA.AUDIT_RECORDS as t
where 
  exists (select 1 from EOMSCHEMA.AUDIT_RECORDS where ID = t.ID and event = 'Activate' and status = 'Completed')
  and
  exists (select 1 from EOMSCHEMA.AUDIT_RECORDS where ID = t.ID and event = 'Create' and status= 'Completed')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this a few ways:

```
select ID, EVENT, STATUS 
FROM EOMSCHEMA.AUDIT_RECORDS
WHERE ID IN(SELECT ID FROM EOMSCHEMA.AUDIT_RECORDS WHERE EVENT = 'CREATE' AND STATUS = 'SUCCESS')
AND ID IN(SELECT ID FROM EOMSCHEMA.AUDIT_RECORDS WHERE EVENT = 'ACTIVATE' AND STATUS= 'SUCCESS');
```

This method uses a series of sub-queries to make sure that all conditions are met and will pull back all of the rows associated with the IDs that passed the checks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of records, this might be slower, but should get you what you are looking for.

You didn't specify which version of sql.  This is MSSQL so you might have to make minor tweaks.

```
SELECT 
COMPLETED.ID, 
COMPLETED.EVENT, 
COMPLETED.STATUS AS CompletedStatus, 
CREATED.STATUS as CreatedStatus

FROM

(SELECT ID, EVENT, STATUS
from EOMSCHEMA.AUDIT_RECORDS
where (event = 'Activate' and status = 'Completed') ) AS COMPLETED

INNER JOIN

(SELECT ID, EVENT, STATUS
from EOMSCHEMA.AUDIT_RECORDS
where (event = 'CREATE' and status = 'Completed') ) AS CREATED

on COMPLETED.ID = CREATED.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from records where eventlog='activate' and 
statuslog='success' and  id in (select id from test where 
eventlog='create' and statuslog ='success');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines..

```
select * from audit_records 
where id in (select id 
             from audit_records  
             group by id 
             having avg(case when status = 'Success' then 1 else 0 end) = 1);
```